# Spring Application doesn´t start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im learning Spring Boot with kotlin and develop my first application.
I´ve got many issues by starting my Application and i don´t know why.. here is my stacktrace:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userGroupRepository' defined in
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository
> defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> FrozenListVoneApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create
> query for method public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.FrozenListVoneApplicationKt.main(FrozenListVoneApplication.kt:18)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6] Caused by:
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create
> query for method public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]     ... 21 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for
> method public abstract kotlin.Pair
> com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.repositories.UserGroupRepository.createOrUpdate(com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.models.entities.UserGroupEntity)!
> No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    ... 43 common frames omitted
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'!   at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    ... 47 common frames omitted
> 
> 
> Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is a example Repository( all repos looks like this):

```
@Repository
interface UserGroupRepository : JpaRepository<UserGroupEntity, Long> {
    fun createOrUpdate(entity: UserGroupEntity) : Pair<Boolean, UserGroupEntity> {
        val existing = if(entity.id != null) findById(entity.id!!) else Optional.ofNullable(null)
        val created: Boolean?
        val backEntity: UserGroupEntity = save(entity)
        created = !existing.isPresent
        return created to backEntity
    }
}
```

And yes of course i´d tried to fix the issue with an Annotation by starting the spring Context:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
class FrozenListVoneApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<FrozenListVoneApplication>(*args)
}
```

I think i have a mistake with my Properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/Frozenlist
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

(im using xampp)

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "UserGroups")
class UserGroupEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    var name : String? = null

    @OneToMany
    private lateinit var storageEntity: List<StorageEntity>

    @OneToMany
    private lateinit var recipes: List<RecipeEntity>

    @OneToMany
    private lateinit var favoritesRecipes: List<RecipeEntity>

    @OneToMany
    private lateinit var shoppingListEntities: List<ShoppingListEntity>

    @OneToMany
    private lateinit var users: Set<UserEntity>

    @ManyToOne
    public lateinit var address: AddressEntity
}
```

And my dto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class UserGroupDto : Serializable {
    var id: Long? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var address: AddressDto? = null
    var isValid: Boolean = false
    val storageEntity: MutableList<StorageDto> = mutableListOf()
    val recipes: MutableList<RecipeDto?> = mutableListOf()
    val favoritesRecipes: MutableList<RecipeDto> = mutableListOf()
    val shoppingListEntities: MutableList<ShoppingListDto?> = mutableListOf()
}
```

if i change my repomethod name to saveOrUpdate(in my repository) i have different errors:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table ingredients (id bigint not null, amount double precision not null, group varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.miguel.frozenlist.frozenlistvone.FrozenListVoneApplicationKt.main(FrozenListVoneApplication.kt:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1608) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) en...' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:270) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:358) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:133) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:815) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:754) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:673) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:616) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.executeInternal(Statement.java:906) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:1031) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:441) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

for more informations please look my github repo:
https://github.com/MiguelSchool/FrozenListVone

Comment: The error log  shows: No property 'create' found for type 'UserGroupEntity'. Have you checked this error?

Comment: I´ven´t got a create property. Id add a method to my repository createOrUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

While analysing the logs I could see the below line.

> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group
> varchar(255) not null

`group` is a keyword in SQL. That's the issue. So change this to something else like *grp* etc.

Comment: okay, but its someting with my method in the repository